# RuntimeError: Inference tensors cannot be saved for backward. To work around you can make a clone to get a normal tensor and use it in autograd

Tags: pytorch

when: the program start the next epoch after validation

How to modify or set for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

torch.inference_mode -> torch.no_grad

Comment: What do you mean by this? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
with torch.inference_mode():
    # Some tensor operations
```

Change it to:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    # Some tensor operations
```

Comment: Doesn't the accepted answer already say this?

Comment: It kinda does say this but no elaboration, this answer is way easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You need to instantiate the model again before defining the optimizer, training loop

```
model_0 = TinyVGG(3, 10, len(train_data.classes)).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model_0.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

and train your model!